# Getting additional blank pages while creating report in vb.net 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, reporting, localreport

I have created a report using .rdlc file.

The output is generated fine of single page but when I go to the print preview or give print command it displays first page of the report and an additional blank page without single line.  What should I do to tackle this bug?

Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this in ASP.NET or a desktop app (e.g. WinForms)? It might be that the paper size and margins of the report need to be set or tweaked...If you're in a WinForms world then perhaps [this](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=6718&lngWId=10) would be of use....HTH, Nathan

Comment: I am generating this report in desktop application. @nkvu

Comment: Sounds like it could be a margin issue - I have had that in some of my reports. Did you try the code in the link in my previous comment? (I'd be interested to hear if it did or did not work for you)

Answer (score 1):

Check your math on the header, body, and footer. These need to be less than the total page width and height minus the margins. If you are even .001 over, it will kick out a blank page when you export